# using as.ppp on data frame to create marked process

Tags: spatstat

I am using a data frame to create a marked point process using `as.ppp` function. I get an error `Error: is.numeric(x) is not TRUE`. The data I am using is as follows:

`dput(head(pointDataUTM[,1:2]))`

```
structure(list(POINT_X = c(439845.0069, 450018.3603, 451873.2925, 
446836.5498, 445040.8974, 442060.0477), POINT_Y = c(4624464.56, 
4629024.646, 4624579.758, 4636291.222, 4614853.993, 4651264.579
)), .Names = c("POINT_X", "POINT_Y"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I can see that the first two columns are numeric, so I do not know why it is a problem.

```
> str(pointDataUTM)
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   5028 obs. of  31 variables:
 $ POINT_X      : num  439845 450018 451873 446837 445041 ...
 $ POINT_Y      : num  4624465 4629025 4624580 4636291 4614854 ...
```

Then I also checked for NA, which shows no NA

```
> sum(is.na(pointDataUTM$POINT_X))
[1] 0
> sum(is.na(pointDataUTM$POINT_Y))
[1] 0
```

When I tried even only the first two columns of the data.frame, the error I get on using as.ppp is this:

```
Error: is.numeric(x) is not TRUE
5.stop(sprintf(ngettext(length(r), "%s is not TRUE", "%s are not all TRUE"), ch), call. = FALSE, domain = NA)
4.stopifnot(is.numeric(x))
3.ppp(X[, 1], X[, 2], window = win, marks = marx, check = check)
2.as.ppp.data.frame(pointDataUTM[, 1:2], W = studyWindow)
1.as.ppp(pointDataUTM[, 1:2], W = studyWindow)
```

Could someone tell me what is the mistake here and why I get the not numeric error?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm on the phone, so can't check but I think it is happens because you have a tibble and not a data.frame. Please try to convert to a data.frame using as.data.frame first.

Comment: Yes, this may be the case, because I used dplyr to create the data frame from a csv.

Answer (score 1):

The critical check is whether `PointDataUTM[,1]` is numeric, rather than `PointDataUTM$POINT_X`.

Since `PointDataUTM` is a `tbl` object, and `tbl` is a function from the `dplyr` package, what is probably happening is that the subset operator for the `tbl` class is returning a data frame, and not a numeric vector, when a single column is extracted. Whereas the `$` operator returns a numeric vector.

I suggest you convert your data to `data.frame` using `as.data.frame()` before calling `as.ppp`.

In the next version of `spatstat` we will make our code more robust against this kind of problem.

Comment: Yes, x and y are the first two columns as you see in my dput statement. I checked with both column index and df$name.